# Refresh the page after successfully submitted

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have modal form, I have a problem getting rid of the input file name value after the submission is successful, I want to refresh the page it self after succeed submit.

here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['postFlag']) && is_numeric($_POST['postFlag'])) {

        $postFlag = $_POST['postFlag'];
        switch ($postFlag) {

            case 1:

                if($this->setPostVars() && $this->checkPostVars()) {
                    $this->setReceipients();
                    $this->sendEmail();
                    $this->writeRecord();
                    $this->returnEcho(1, 'Sending successful!');
                }

            break;
        }
    }
```

I tried the `header('Location: ');` it saves the data but it gives me an error 
Also `echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>"`

Comment: what error does it give you?

Comment: it gives me a sever error

Comment: @Mech do you have any solution?

Comment: which input file name are you looking to remove?

Comment: @Mech Hi, the one that user's inputed on input type="file". after the success submit. the input file value is still there

Comment: Whatever the name of that input is, put it into my answer. It will clear it for you.

Comment: the name of the input file is `name="file"` and `name="resume"`
`$_POST['postFlag'] = "";` <== how can I put in there?

Comment: or maybe suggest on how to when the form was successfully submitted refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

As a Newbie developer, I usually have the opposite issue.

Only reasons not to reload a page when submitting a form method POST:

1. Your form is returning false, thus the page not reloading.
2. You are using ajax and have an exit() in your php, therefore the server doesn't send you the whole page, but just what you placed inside the exit().

You can hardcode it by using:

```
echo "<script>location.reload(true);</script>";
```

Comment: Hi, tried your suggestion but it still wont work. it gives me an internal server error. maybe I put in the wrong line. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){            // <-- add the below within this jquery tag
        $("form").submit(function(e) {       // <-- activates on form submit
            $("#file-selected").html('');    // <-- sets data to ''
            e.preventDefault();              // <-- prevents html() from filling back up
        });                                  // <-- closing tags for form submit
    });
```

Comment: Hi tried ur suggestion, still wont clear the values

Comment: that's very strange because you are redefining it as something else. Can you please do a `var_dump()` under the `$_POST['fileinputname'] ="";` and see what happens?

Comment: it gives me an string

Comment: btw the value of that input was on a <label>

Comment: `$('#file-selected').html(data.result.filename);` I want to make that empty after success submit. how to achieve that using php?

Comment: That was a very important piece of information that you left out :P

Comment: yeah, Im sorry about that, any suggestion?

Comment: So, that part is jQuery (that's what the `$` represents in `$(`). I'll update my answer. You should update your post for future users.